# Can $s$ be any number in $s^x = x \bmod N$, where $N = p \cdot q$ for de Jonge / Chaum?

Tags: rsa, signature

I was reading about some way to imagine the signature of a message using the RSA problem :

> Let $N$ be the product of two prime numbers $p$ and $q$. Let $s$ be
> the signature of a message $s$ (provided that such $s$ exists) defined
> as $s^x = x \bmod N$.

Later on the following requirement is made on $x$ : $x$ is prime with $\phi(N)$.

I do not understand this requirement. And why with $\phi(N)$ and not $N$ ?

In my understanding, $s$ must be prime with $N$, so that I will be able to use Euler's theorem at some point. But what is all about $x$ and $\phi(N)$ ?

Comment: RSA induces a group whose order is $k \phi(N) + 1$, thus not related to $N$ itself. Hence the requirement must be related to $\phi(N)$, not $N$.

Comment: Actually, there's no requirement that $s$ be relatively prime to $N$; for a toy example, $N=15, s=12$ is a valid signature of $x=3$.